# Upgrading from Debian 8 (Jessie) to 9 (Stretch)

Tags: debian, apt, debian-jessie, debian-stretch

I am in the process of updating my Debian 8 (Jessie) machine to Debian 9 (Stretch)

Current kernel version is :

```
# uname -a
Linux host 4.9.0-0.bpo.6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1~bpo8+1 (2018-05-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Right now Ive made sure that all my packages are upto date on Debian 8.

```
# apt update
.
.
.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder contains the following:

```
# ls -ltrh
total 16K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 575 Nov 22  2017 jessie.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  72 Nov 22  2017 download_docker_com_linux_debian.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  93 Jan 18  2018 jessie-backports.list
```

OS details are:

```
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Now as part of my actual upgrade to Debian 9, I've done added the following file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
# cat  stretch.list


deb https://my-repository.com/debian/       stretch         main contrib non-free
deb https://my-repository.com/debian/       stretch-updates     main contrib non-free
deb https://my-repository.com/debian/   stretch-proposed-updates    main contrib non-free

deb https://my-repository.com/debian-security/  stretch/updates     main contrib non-free
```

Now that Ive added this file, I did an `apt update` and can see that it is indeed reading the stretch sources.

And when I do an `apt upgrade` it does nothing and says `All packages are up to date.`

The below 2 commands return `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

```
# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

# apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It doesn't seem to be upgrading to Debian 9. Any idea what Im missing here ?

Comment: In case it's a repository priority issue, could you add the output of `apt-cache policy base-files` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you disabled the Jessie repo's? If not, please try that, execute `apt update && apt upgrade` if that was succesful try executing `apt dist-upgrade` and reboot to finish and confirm the upgrade.